# PHP file renaming mysterious no error images losts

Tags: php, file, upload, rename, move

I got bunch of photos with random names i want to post them online so they need to be renamed as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc;

I wrote following code to achive this

```
$i = 1;
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($path.'/'.$file)) {
            $oldname   = $path.'/'.$file;
            $path_info = pathinfo($oldname);            
            rename($oldname, $path.'/'.($i).'.'.'jpg');
            echo "Old name = <b>".$oldname."</b></br>";
            echo "New name = <b>".$path.'/'.($i).'.'.'jpg'."</b></br></br>";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

and magic happened there were 22 files in the folder after running this script only 14 pics were remaining with names 1.jpg,10.jpg to 22.jpg when i refreshed again then there were only 6 pics remaining with names 1.jpg to 6.jpg now at this point they didn't change even after refreshing again and again.

I tried commenting out `rename($oldname, $path.'/'.($i).'.'.'jpg');`just to see what old names and new names being generated and those were totlly fine like whatever the old name is new name is generated what i was wanting 1.jpg to 22.jpg

I tried almost same peice of code to change .JPG extension to .jpg extension as linux server is case sensitive about file naming while windows isn't this code worked fine all time;

```
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($path.'/'.$file)) {
            $oldname   = $path.'/'.$file;
            $path_info = pathinfo($oldname);
            echo $sub= substr($file,0,-4);
            echo "<br>";
            rename($oldname, $path.'/'.($sub).'.'.'jpg');
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

It's 2:40 AM of the morning in INDIA and I am just a student this problem is not letting me go to sleep mode please help me.

Comment: I put my bet on a path problem. Print out the full paths, check permissions...

Comment: Are any of the original names like `1.jpg` to `22.jpg`? If they are, then you'll delete those files when you try to rename one of the other files to the same name.

Comment: Did you check php_errors.log?

Comment: nope i am working locally and I have turned on show error i can see all other errors bt for reference i am pasting error log just in case if it helps

[Thu Mar 03 21:38:54.867100 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4512:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Mar 03 21:38:55.010100 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4512:tid 260] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Mar 03 23:15:19.182000 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 4512:tid 1628] [client fe80::15db:ddeb:c395:4eee:50562] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C

Comment: Yes My original names have 1.jpg and so on names on many files is it the reason?

Comment: and i place my bet its not a path problem i have been looking addresses since 3 hours $path="imgs/photography"; 
if the problem is with path then why files in photography folder gets affected when this script runs?

Answer (score 0):

After looping through rethinking() i got the point why this piece of code didn't worked and why it worked for the extension renaming.

rename function takes the 2 parameters the old name of the file and new name with location, it can move files as well, if there is already a file exist with same name in new location or same location it will simply overwrite it and will not through any error.

To understand this lets take an example there are 22 images in photography folder named from 1.jpg to 22.jpg but with random order like 1.jpg,10.jpg,15.jpg etc.

then this code will take 1.jpg and rename it with 1.jpg so far so good but next time it loops it will take 10.jpg (which is the second file in the folder) and rename it with 2.jpg ok that is what was expected from the code but hold on a second there already exist a file named 2.jpg it is simply overwritten by the code without any error thus causing data lose.

Now you will say why the hack image come in order like 1.jpg, 10.jpg and if there exist 2.jpg than why they are not ordered as 1.jpg and 2.jpg?
the answer is simple some pic have .jpg and some .JPG pics with .JPG got the precedence.

To overcome from this problem you will need to do what most of software does ex. WinRAR you will need a temporary folder to move your files to then move the files again to source folder the code will go something like following.

```
<?php
$path="test";
$i = 1;
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($path.'/'.$file)) {
            $oldname   = $path.'/'.$file;
            $path_info = pathinfo($oldname);            
            rename($oldname, "tmp".'/'.($i).'.'.'jpg');
            echo "Old name = <b>".$oldname."</b></br>";
            echo "New name = <b>"."tmp".'/'.($i).'.'.'jpg'."</b></br></br>";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
$path="tmp";
$i = 1;
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($path.'/'.$file)) {
            $oldname   = $path.'/'.$file;
            $path_info = pathinfo($oldname);            
            rename($oldname, "test".'/'.($i).'.'.'jpg');
            echo "Old name = <b>".$oldname."</b></br>";
            echo "New name = <b>".$path.'/'.($i).'.'.'jpg'."</b></br></br>";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

and thanks everyone for not helping me out its just because of you I did it myself.